# How to get rid of mdDialog console error cannot read property element of null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `Left_template_view_html` and `center_template_view_html`

On click of `md-button` in `Left_template_view_html`

Am trying to open a `mdDialog` on `document.body`

what I have to provide in parent : `angular.element()`?
In below code to avoid console error. Functionality works fine for me.

```
 $scope.showAdvancedSelection = function(ev,templateURL) {

$mdDialog.show({
            controller: DialogController,
            template: templateURL,
            parent: angular.element(document.getElementById(document.body)),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose: true
        })
        .then(function (answer) {
            $scope.status = 'true';
        }, function () {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
   };
```

error

> angular.js:14525 TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null
>       at f (angular-material.min.js:16)
>       at angular-material.min.js:16
>       at angular.js:16832
>       at m.$digest (angular.js:17971)
>       at m.$apply (angular.js:18269)
>       at l (angular.js:12387)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.A.onload (angular.js:12541) "Possibly unhandled rejection: {}"

Comment: app.config(['$qProvider', function ($qProvider) {
    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
}]);                   ------>this code solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

use -

> parent: angular.element(document.body)